# Any trim functions in matlab?

Tags: matlab

If I have an input like [1 2 3; 4.0 c] and I want it to output it like 1234.0c in matlab. What function can I use ? I am looking for something like trim in php.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: this is not a valid MATLAB argument! you can't have anything like this

Comment: @Momo It would be nice to mark an answer as "accepted" to officially inform the answerer that his answer was best or give some extra information about your question.

Comment: Thanks, I may have written this in the wrong way, it is a string output `[1 2 3; 4.0 c]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isstrprop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isstrprop.html) function with approppriate categories. For your case,

```
>> str = '1 2 3; 4.0 c';
>> str(isstrprop(str, 'alphanum') | str == '.')

ans =

1234.0c
```

You can use functions like [`isletter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isletter.html), [`isnumeric`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isnumeric.html), etc. if you like.

Besides, you can create your own function in one line as follows

```
>> myTrim = @(x)(x(isstrprop(x, 'alphanum') | x == '.'));
>> myTrim(str)

ans =

1234.0c
```

Note that you ask `[1 2 3; 4.0 c]` as an input which is not a proper syntax for MATLAB. I assumed you wanted to ask for a string. In addition, trim actually implies removing leading and trailing white space from a string and there is [`strtrim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strtrim.html) for this in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to remove any number of spaces from inside of a string:

```
>> a = char(' he  llo wor   ld ');
>> a(isspace(a)) = [] %replaces all of the space with nothing

a =

helloworld
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what about special characters ?

Comment: You can change the `isspace(a)` part to pretty much anything you want. ex: `a(a=='%') = []` replaces all the `%` with nothing

Answer (score 1):

It is not a valid MATLAB argument.
But if you have something like

```
a = ['1', '2' ,'3'; '4', '.','c'];
```

you can use

```
a(:)'
```

to get

```
142.3c
```

or

```
a = a';
a(:)'
```

to get

```
123.4c
```